# Error when Registering Scalable Targets within my Service Auto Scaling on AWS ECS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, autoscaling, aws-fargate

I tried registering scalable targets for my autoscaling with my service and cluster name specified within `--resource-id` but I am receiving an error
`RegisterScalableTarget operation: Unsupported service namespace, resource type or scalable dimension.`

```
    --service-namespace ecs \
    --scalable-dimension ecs:service:DesiredCount \
    --resource-id fargate-service/default/fargate-cluster \
    --min-capacity 1 \
    --max-capacity 10
```

It tells me that `--service-namespace` ECS is the issue but in the example code for deploying a registered target to ECS that this is a valid way to format the code? My service is called fargate-service and cluster is called fargate-cluster as shown.

I'm not sure what other details to provide to get a solution but if I am missing anything important be sure to mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems not correct:

```
--resource-id fargate-service/default/fargate-cluster
```

The [form should](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-service-auto-scaling/) be:

```
--resource-id service/<your-cluster-name>/<your-service-name>
```